# Error: (-1004) Can't bind: topic

Tags: apache-kafka

I am getting following error while publishing message to kafka (*Only after I cross a 28,000 messages*),

> Error: (-1004) Can't bind: topic

Please guide me in resolving this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because all the sockets were getting filled up by TCP connections , so once none of the sockets were free , it wasnt been able to bind topic .